# Changing drives in FTP

Tags: rhel, windows, ftp, disk, filezilla

I am using RHEL6 and I connect to FileZilla FTP Server in Windows 2008 Server  which has more than 10 drives.
I have access to all of them but for my user `C:\` is Home Directory.
I want to change to other drives, such as `D:\ Y:\ S:\` etc.
When I type `lcd d:\` it outputs

> no such file or directory

How I can change Windows drives with my Linux command-line FTP client (`ftp`)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make aliases for the drives.

Like `/d for D:\ and /g for G:\`, etc.

See the FAQ https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FAQ#FileZilla_Server_FAQ

Comment: i found another, filezilla-independent solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/155655/change-between-drives-in-filezilla-client